# Excel VBA: Is there a neater way to modify values in Workbook.Names than this?

Tags: excel, vba

I have numerical values stored as `Workbook names`. To modify the content I am currently doing it like this

```vbs
Sub Macro1()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim s As String: s = "Sheet_Row_Height"
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim node, nn
    nn = wb.Names.Item(s).Value
    i = Val(Replace(nn, "=", ""))
    i = i + 1
    wb.Names.Item(s).Delete
    Set node = wb.Names.Add(Name:=s, RefersTo:= i)
End Sub
```

Is there a neater way to do this my give example? It seems like a lot of unnecessary steps to me? I Tried to modify the `Value`, but I did not succeed, so I did as the example above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the value of a name that is not referring to a cell only via it's `Value` property, and you have to remove the `=`, and when writing it you have to add it.

However, you can simplify your code a little bit, there is no need to delete an recreate the name object. And, as a side note, there is no need to write `Names.Item(s)`, you can use `Names(s)` as the `item`-Collection is the so called *default property*.

If you are sure that the name exists and has a numeric value, you can use something like this:

```
Dim n As Name
Set n = wb.Names(s)
n.Value = "=" & Val(Mid(n.Value, 2)) + 1
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed the third line to `n.Value = 1 + Val(Replace(n.Value, "=", ""))` instead. That also worked.